# Is there a way for python to print out itertools.permutations on a word without the list?

Tags: python, python-itertools

So, whenever I run itertools.permutations on a string, it comes out like this:

input code:

```
import itertools
import pprint

pprint.pprint(list(itertools.permutations("par")))
```

My output is this array:

```
[('p', 'a', 'r'),
 ('p', 'r', 'a'),  
 ('a', 'p', 'r'),  
 ('a', 'r', 'p'),  
 ('r', 'p', 'a'),  
 ('r', 'a', 'p')]
```

This is a big problem with larger strings. I need a way to print these out as a normal looking line such as:

```
par
pra
apr
arp
rpa
rap
```

or in a list, like

```
par, pra, apr, arp, rpa, rap
```

I'm new to programming, so if something seems painfully obvious, my bad!

Answer (score 2):

Use `map`:

```
>>> list(map(''.join, itertools.permutations("par")))
['par', 'pra', 'apr', 'arp', 'rpa', 'rap']
```

Or a list comprehension:

```
>>> [''.join(l) for l in itertools.permutations("par")]
['par', 'pra', 'apr', 'arp', 'rpa', 'rap']
>>>
```

Or as @ShadowRanger mentioned, you could do it even better:

```
for x in map(''.join, itertools.permutations("par")):
    print(x)
```

Output:

```
par
pra
apr
arp
rpa
rap
```

Or also:

```
for x, y, z in itertools.permutations("par"):
    print(x + y + z)
```

Comment: I'd suggest an actual loop over the `map` with a `print` call; making an actual `list` is going to blow memory pretty quickly for inputs of meaningful size. Using `map` will actually get a bit of a performance boost over manually `''.join`ing, as it ensures the `tuple` from `permutations` is released immediately (allowing a CPython optimization in `permutations` to reuse said `tuple` on the next loop rather than allocating a new one to be used).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Ah! Yeah good point! Will edit:

Comment: @ShadowRanger Edited mine!

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> for perm in itertools.permutations("par"):
...     print("".join(perm))
... 
par
pra
apr
arp
rpa
rap
```

Answer (score 1):

Use for loop (If you want to print directly)-

```
import itertools
import pprint

a = list(itertools.permutations("par"))

for i,j,k in a:
    print(f'{i}{j}{k}') # Output
```

Or List Comprehension (If you want a list) -

```
output = [f'{i}{j}{k}' for i,j,k in a]
print(output)
```